# How to disable c# ODataController client side query

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, odata, client-side

According to this tutorial: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/using-select-expand-and-value

"Web API 2 adds support for the $expand, $select, and $value options in OData. These options allow a client to control the representation that it gets back from the server"

My question it, how can I disable the representation manipulation done at the client side. In other words, my server makes sure that filtering/selecting etc. are done properly, and thus I do not want the client side to do it again. It is more of an overhead.

Comment: What if you just won't add [Queryable] attribute to method?

Comment: I do not have [Queryable] attribute anywhere though

Comment: 1) Can you provide example of your controller? 2) Why do you need OData controller, if you don't want to use its features, just switch to regular ApiController

Answer (score 1):

I think you misunderstand the purpose of query options like `$expand`, `$select`, etc. They do **not** cause data to be manipulated on the client. Rather, they are instructions to the service. In the Web API OData implementation, query options are typically handled by the `EnableQuery` attribute or the `Queryable` attribute. If you don't use these attributes, then you are responsible for writing the code that handles query options. Or you are free to not support them.

Answer (score 0):

1. In your controller action, like get method, add attribute [EnableQuery] (this is for OData v4)
2. IN your client, send out request like ~/EntitySet?$filter=... & $select = ...

Then the response will only contain the filtered and select content.
Refer to https://github.com/OData/ODataSamples/tree/master/WebApi/v4/ODataQueryableSample to see the example.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom attribute which would inherit from EnableQueryAttribute and then override the ValidateQuery method to limit the allowed query options as well as allowed functions and page size.

```
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.OData;
using System.Web.OData.Query;

public class SecureApiQueryAttribute : EnableQueryAttribute
{
    public override void ValidateQuery(HttpRequestMessage request, ODataQueryOptions queryOptions)
    {
        base.AllowedQueryOptions = AllowedQueryOptions.None;
        base.PageSize = 30;
        base.AllowedFunctions = AllowedFunctions.AllFunctions;
        base.ValidateQuery(request, queryOptions);
    }
}
```

Then you can use this custom attribute like this

```
    [SecureApiQuery]
    public IHttpActionResult Get([FromODataUri] int? key = null)
    {
    }
```